# Slow Performance WebServer GoogleCloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This is just a statement not a Question.

We had some webservers in google cloud that were clone onsite. The network speeds from time to time were extremely slow.

Solution is to change MTU from default 1500 to 1460 to match GCP.

We have a direct fiber connection to google which was 100 times faster than external connection that lead to this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to change MTU from default 1500 to 1460 to match GCP. This is done in your network card settings on the server.